# Is it possible to await a page entrance animation?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, modern-ui

I have the following animation set on a scrollviewer:

```
<ScrollViewer.Transitions>
  <TransitionCollection>
    <EntranceThemeTransition />
  </TransitionCollection>
</ScrollViewer.Transitions>
```

This brings me a nice animation where the scrollviewer (and it's content) enters from the right on the page load. But I have some content inside the scrollviewer which need some time to load from a database. I want to await this loading and then start the animation. How can I await the loading and trigger the animation on my own instead of on every page enter?

Comment: Have you played with [`IsStaggeringEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition.isstaggeringenabled) property ?

Comment: @Xyroid Yes, but it makes no differend. The animation still starts on page enter.

Comment: Check out the WinRTXamlToolkit. It has some AwaitableUI helpers. I think they took the AwaitableUI helpers from another project, so you may want to look there if you need it to be standalone.

Comment: @NateDiamond Looks good. But do you have any examples? Can't find one online.

Comment: In the Codeplex project, there should be a sample app that goes over how to use all of the components (or, at least, most of the components).